# How can I replace text/images in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making an app with tkinter that reads Information from a file (Author, Message, Image's name) and displays it like a visual novel game. Pressing 'continue' *should* replace current info with info stored in a different(next) message.

story.txt looks like this:

> Man_img ++ John ++ My name is John!
>
> Woman_img ++ Monika ++ Hi! I'm Monika!

Instead, I'm getting a bug: Text stays untouched and the image disappears.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
s = open('story.txt', 'r+')
lines = s.read().splitlines()
s.close()
i=0

display = ''
speakervar = ''
textvar = ''
speaker = ''
text = ''


def next_scene():
    global lines, display, i, label, photo, speakervar, textvar, speaker, text
    line = lines[i]
    values = line.split(' ++ ')

    display = 'Images/'+ values[0] + '.png'
    speakervar = values[1]
    textvar = values[2]

    photo = PhotoImage(file=display)
    label = Label(root, image=photo)
    speaker = Label(root, text=speakervar)
    text = Label(root, text=textvar)


    i+=1

next_scene()


continuebutton = Button(text="Continue", fg="black", command=next_scene)


photo = PhotoImage(file=display)
label = Label(root, image=photo)
speaker = Label(root, text=speakervar)
text = Label(root, text=textvar)


speaker.grid(column=0, row=1)
text.grid(column=0, row=2)
label.grid(column=0, row=0)
continuebutton.grid(column=0, row=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @BryanOakley Is that the case here? MBee is using a global to store the photo.

Comment: @scotty3785: you're right, I didn't notice the global declaration. Thanks. I've remove my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
speaker = Label(root, text=speakervar)
```

You are creating a new widget each time rather than just updating the text.

to update the text just do

```
speaker['text'] = speakervar
```

A similar method can be applied for changing the PhotoImage

Comment: I used ```speaker['text'] = speakervar``` instead and it worked. Thanks!